# How to center an entire LinearLayout in xml?

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-linearlayout

I have a few vertically oriented elements in a LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
            ... />

    <Button
            ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

These elements do not take up the entire vertical space of the application, and I want them to be vertically centered. How do I do this?

Comment: as I know, set all child's  `height` to `wrap_content`, and use `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the attribute [android:layout_gravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_gravity) positions the view with respect to its parent, meaning their enclosing layout. In your case, the problem is, that you have no enclosing layout. I know, it's confusing because one might think that the LinearLayout would center itsself in the root window, but even when it comes to attributes which basically refer
to their parent e.g "[android:layout_centerInParent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android%3alayout_centerInParent)" they always refer to their enclosing layout ("parent"). By the way, "LinearLayout" doesn't support those attributes.

My ideas to solve your problem:

**Solution 1: put your LinearLayout in an enclosing layout:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

     <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Textbox1"  />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Textbox2"  />     

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Solution 2: let the containing views align themselves**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Textbox1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_2"
        android:layout_below="@id/textview_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Textbox2" />      

    <Button
        android:layout_below="@id/textview_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Layout_gravity="center_vertical" does not work on a vertical LinearLayout.

I'd say you can set `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and `android:gravity="center_vertical"` on the LinearLayout.

Answer (score 2):

Try out this way :

> ```
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
>     android:orientation="vertical" >    
> <TextView
>     android:id="@+id/title"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:gravity="center"
>     android:text="lhkabhfksbj" />    
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

Just set the gravity of views to "center" . I think this is what you want.